# Breaking table contents on responsive email

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design

I'm coding a responsive email, and I'm running onto some troubles with the behavior of some its tables. Please check the attached picture, for the desired effect.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/58655025/mail_scenario.jpg
(left: "normal" behavior; right: responsive behavior, when the view width is <= 320px)

I'm not exactly sure of how many elements these blocks (both rectangular and the square ones; number of block elements and contents are dynamic) will have in total, so I want to keep the HTML as dynamic as possible. So, every time a new element is added to each block, it's placed at the right of the previous one and when they cannot fit on that line (due to email's max-width of 620px), I'd like for them to continue below.
And that's the part I'm not able to do. Instead of breaking below, the elements keep growing in the same line, ignoring the email's max-width property.

I'd like for the implementation to be table-based only, in order to guarantee the maximum email-client support as possible.

What can I do to achieve this? Any other suggestion?

Please, check this fiddle for a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/afe33fhv/

Or the HTML code, as required:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* Client-specific Styles */
            #outlook a {padding:0;}
            body {width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; color:#756d85; font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
            body.outlook img { width: auto !important; max-width: none !important;}
            .ExternalClass {width:100%;}
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height:100%;}
            .backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height:100% !important;}
            img {outline:none; text-decoration:none; border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
            a img {border:none;}
            .image_fix {display:block;}
            p {margin: 0px 0px !important;}
            table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
            table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }
            a {color: #756d85;text-decoration: none;text-decoration:none!important;}
            table[class=full] { width: 100%; clear:both; }

            /*IPAD STYLES*/
            @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
                a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #000;
                    pointer-events: none;
                    cursor: default;
                }
                table[class=devicewidth] {width:440px !important; text-align:center !important;}
                table[class=devicewidthinner] {width:420px !important; text-align:center !important;}
                table[class=devicewidthsocial] {width:200px! important; text-align:center !important;}
                img[class=banner] {width:440px !important; height:220px !important;}
                img[class=colimg2] {width:440px !important; height:220px !important;}
            }

            /*IPHONE STYLES*/
            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
                a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: #000;
                    pointer-events: none;
                    cursor: default;
                }
                table[class=devicewidth] {width:300px !important; text-align:center !important;}
                table[class=devicewidthinner] {width:260px !important; text-align:center !important;}
                table[class=devicewidthsocial] {width: 200px!important; text-align:center !important;}
                img[class=banner] {width: 280px!important; height:140px!important;}
                img[class=colimg2] {width: 280px!important; height:140px!important;}
                td[class=mobile-hide]{display:none !important;}
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0">
        <center>

            <!-- | Horizontal blocks | -->
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="backgroundTable">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="620" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth" bgcolor="#f2f2f2">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Element 1 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="300" height="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="300" height="80" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#7c84ca">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr><td width="100%">1</td></tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- Element 2 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="300" height="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="300" height="80" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#bdaabf">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr><td width="100%">2</td></tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- Element 3 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="300" height="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="300" height="80" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#d26ec1">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr><td width="100%">3</td></tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- Element 4 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="300" height="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <table width="300" height="80" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#d85c79">
                                                                <tbody>
                                                                    <tr><td width="100%">4</td></tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                                                            </table>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr><td width="100%" height="10" style="font-size:1px; line-height:1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <!-- | Square blocks | -->
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="backgroundTable">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table width="620" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="devicewidth" bgcolor="#f2f2f2">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <!-- Element 1 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="140" height="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#8eb7c2">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- Element 2 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="140" height="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#8ec296">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- Element 3 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="140" height="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#636a34">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                        <!-- Element 4 -->
                                        <td>
                                            <table width="140" height="140" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#c17b01">
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to scrap the tables. Set all the blocks to `display: inline-block;` and they will automatically wrap around to the next line if the parent container hasn't got enough width left.

By using media queries, you can make sure the boxes parent container can only take on certain widths, creating your desired effect.

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/spkzj05b/2/

Here is a list of css features supported in popular email clients: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Here is a tool to test the rendering in different email clients: https://litmus.com/email-testing

Comment: I know how to achieve this behavior with divs; but the thing here is the template will be for emails solely, and divs support by email clients is not the best, as far as I know.
Is this answer based on your email templating experience?

Comment: @NunoM What do you mean email clients don't support divs? Of course they do; they're one of the most basic html elements. Why don't you tell me which particular css features I've used which aren't compatible with email clients (and which email clients), and I can try and work around them.

Comment: I've added some links which might be helpful for this.

Comment: I didn't say divs are not supported. What I've read so far (although some of those articles date back to 2010) is, in order to keep emails working well with multi email clients, divs should be avoided. That was it. I'll try your approach and test it on some clients. I'll mark your answer after that, if you don't mind. By the way, thanks for the links.

Comment: @NunoM By looking at the support chart, it looks as if a mixture of inline-block and floats will make it supported by most email clients. The reason why I dismissed tables is because I don't think what you're after is possible with tables, unless you render 2 tables with totally different layout, then use media queries to hide one of them appropriately. However, with either method you're going to have a problem with Outlook, since it doesn't support `display`, `float` or media queries.